# Piping input into a Python quick and dirty one-liner

Tags: python, bash

I know I can get stdin input (through `sys.stdin.read()`) into a script. But how would a Python one-liner work? If I wanted to pipe a string and invert it using Python, how would it look like? That is, I want the equivalent of string[::-1] but for the piping.

Comment: So... you're calling the script from the command line?

Comment: @Denziloe: I'm not using any script, just a pipe,

Comment: You're not "using a script"? So what exactly are you doing with Python? I don't think your question makes any sense, tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve here in simple terms.

Answer (score 3):

```
print(sys.stdin.read()[-2::-1])
```

`-2` is for stripping the last empty line. Some utilities like `echo` add a newline at the end by default.